# jquery ends with selector doesn't work with number at end

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<tr data-page-group-field="swot_opportunity_1" class="form_rowstyle1">
    <td class="form_leftcolumn">Opportunity 2</td>
    <td class="form_midcolumn"><input type="text" maxlength="100" data-page-group="swot_opportunity" id="edit_swot_opportunity_1" placeholder=""></td>
    <td class="form_rightcolumn"><img src="/app/image/button_up.png" width="31" height="26" alt="up" id="button_swot_up_1"> <img src="/app/image/button_down.png" width="31" height="26" alt="down" id="button_swot_down_1"></td>
</tr>
```

and need to match the input field by the number at the end:

```
$('input[id=^"edit_swot_"][id$="_2"]')).id));
```

I cannot get this to work, is there a limitation of not having a number at the end?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dro3knq3/

Comment: try this selector `$('[id^="edit_swot_"][id$="_2"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** selector to get the id

```
 alert($('input[id^="edit_swot_"][id$="_2"]').attr("id"));
                //^^^ error in code
```

OR

```
 $('input[id^="edit_swot_"][id$="_2"]')[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `id=^"edit_swot_"` to `id^="edit_swot_"`

Look at [jQuery Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
alert($('input[id^="edit_swot_"][id$="_2"]').attr("id"));
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dro3knq3/2/)